# Keyboard Navigation and Accessibility for custom SWT widgets

Tags: java, eclipse, accessibility, swt

I am trying to build a simple custom SWT widget and i want to ensure that it is accessible. I know that accessbility encompasses a lot of factors, but as a starting point, i would at least like to make it navigable via the keyboard.

This is a simplified view of my custom control. I have overridden the 'Canvas' class in SWT.

[image: SWT Custom Control]

The 'Third Button' is my custom control. Now, the 'tab' toggles through only the first two buttons. I would also like it to focus on my custom control when i tab through the controls. Is there any way to make this possible?

Also, are there any general guidelines on making custom SWT controls accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the SWT snippets are very good in conveying information on accessibility and achieving keyboard navigation, among other things.

For my specific question, [the snippets on accessibility](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets#accessibility) are useful. This one snippet on [how to achieve tab-traversal of a Canvas element](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet21.java?view=co) is spot-on.

This [Eclipse accessibility article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Accessibility/index.html) provides an useful overview of how to make your SWT application accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The following link may help with SWT accessibility since it goes over setting tab order, cursor highlight, etc. http://www.borderlandconsulting.com/bc/articles/swt_tips_and_tricks_1.php

Comment: Thanks for that, Jared. It was useful too.